# apache2 woven deeply into ubuntu18.04

Tags: apache2, systemd

How can I get rid of apache2 (without totally removing it)?
I found there is 
/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service

thus starting apache2 at reboot (whether /etc/init.d/apache2 exists or not).

Is there something like systemctl remove service.apache2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can disble apache2 using command:

```
sudo systemctl disable apache2.service
```

Or you can mask it

```
sudo systemctl mask apache2.service
```

Comment: ... for the sake of completeness: this will disable autostarting apache at boot time. To stop it immediately, run `sudo systemctl stop apache2.service` or `sudo systemctl disable --now apache2.service` to disable and stop in one go.